# Loop over 2 dictionnaries and append several values to a key

Tags: python, loops, dictionary

I have 2 dictionnaries, the first one is showing some works:

```
d= {"a": "pompier", "b": "policier", "c": "tracteur"}
```

And the second one the adjectives associated with works which are list type

```
d1 = {"a": "[gentil, fort]", "b": "[juste, amicale]", "c": "[fonctionnel, fort, utile]"}
```

I want to append the value from the d1 dictionnary into the d dictionnary to have something looking like this

```
d2 = {"a": "pompier", "[gentil, fort]", "b": "policier", "[juste, amicale]", "c": "tracteur", "[fonctionnel, fort, utile]"}
```

I need to precise, I don't know if there is (in my original file), key from d1 that are not in d dictionnary...

I've tried this code but it returns an error

```
or key, value in d.items():
for key1, value1 in d1.items():
    if key in d1:
        d1[key].append[value1]
    print(d1)

    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 7, in <module>
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'append'
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: Your dictionnary d2 can't be defined, you should re check what output you really want

Comment: You have not said what behaviour you want in the case that a key in d1 does not exist in d.  It would be clearer with an example of this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
d= {"a": "pompier", "b": "policier", "c": "tracteur"}
d1 = {"a": "[gentil, fort]", "b": "[juste, amicale]", "c": "[fonctionnel, fort, utile]"}
d2 = dict()
for key, value in d.items():
    if d1.get(key):
        d2[key] = [value, d1.get(key)]
    else:
        d2[key] = value

print(d2)
```

First of all, you need to define d2. Secondly, you have strings, not lists, so you cannot use append. Instead, you must add them to the list. Here, if a key doesn't exist in d1, it's going to remain just a single value and if it exists, it'll add them to the list.

You have 2 options here. If you want values to always be in a list, just put `d2[key] = [value]`

If you have keys in d1 that do not exist in d, you should do another loop through `d1.items()` and add just the missing ones:

```
for key, value in d1.items():
    if key not in d.keys():
        d2[key] = value
```

Comment: `defaultdict` is useful to avoid all these extra checks.

Comment: I don't think that the question in its existing form is clear enough about what exactly should be in the `else` block. I have asked for clarification.